# Creating a join and COUNT() in Zen Cart

Tags: mysql, join, count, zen-cart

I'm having lots of trouble trying to create a join and count (and then setting the order by it) in Zen cart.

Here's the code:

```
echo $listing_sql = "select " . $select_column_list . " p.products_id, count(opc.products_id), p.products_type, p.master_categories_id, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id, pd.products_description, IF(s.status = 1, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price, IF(s.status =1, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price, p.products_sort_order, p.product_is_call, p.product_is_always_free_shipping, p.products_qty_box_status
   from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd, " .
   TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p left join " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id, " .
   TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " p2c left join " . TABLE_SPECIALS . " s on p2c.products_id = s.products_id
   join " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " opc on opc.products_id = p.products_id
   where p.products_status = 1
     and p.products_id = p2c.products_id
     and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
     and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "'
     and p2c.categories_id = '" . (int)$current_category_id . "'" .
     $alpha_sort . " ORDER BY count(opc.products_id)";
```

I want to count opc.products_id and then set it as ORDER BY count(opc.products_id) at the end. Not sure where I'm going wrong, many thanks!

Costa

Answer (score 0):

Hard to not get lost in your code, but thing you need to do:

1) make a query that selects products like you want, just without count(opc.products_id) and sorting for now. Test it. All products should have only one row each (no duplicity), then...

2) edit your code with focus on these three highlighted parts:

```
echo $listing_sql = "select " . $select_column_list . " p.products_id, count(opc.products_id), p.products_type, p.master_categories_id, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id, pd.products_description, IF(s.status = 1, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price, IF(s.status =1, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price, p.products_sort_order, p.product_is_call, p.product_is_always_free_shipping, p.products_qty_box_status

,count(opc.products_id) as opc_count

from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd, " .
TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p left join " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id, " .
TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " p2c left join " . TABLE_SPECIALS . " s on p2c.products_id = s.products_id

 join " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " opc on opc.products_id = p.products_id

where p.products_status = 1
  and p.products_id = p2c.products_id
  and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
  and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$_SESSION['languages_id'] . "'
  and p2c.categories_id = '" . (int)$current_category_id . "'" .
  $alpha_sort . "

 GROUP BY p.products_id ORDER BY opc_count ";
```

Comment: Thanks David, that still doesn't work, here is the vanilla code that works properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/mpjshvs4/

Dumped it into jsfiddle so it remains legible.

Comment: You could have at least told us the SQL Error message. AND computed query, it is pretty pointless when there are unknowns behind these variables and constants. I believe at least one error is, that `$alpha_sort` contains `ORDER BY` clause. You can't have two of these, you need to merge them.

Comment: Sorry about that David, here is a screenshot:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/dmgp5j6g7lne63e/Screenshot.png

Comment: If there is any information that would help just let me know, I am a little over my head with this feature. I don't get along well with joins.

Comment: A screenshot? Really? Come on. You have to select the text, press CTRL+C, then open pastebin.com and paste it there. Also, it would help a lot to get the actual MySQL message, not "Sorry, a boo boo happened, you are f*****" Zen-cart printed after it got the error. Try adding print_r(mysql_error()) at the line behind where the query got executed and failed.

Comment: Okay, I've got it this far but the problem I am having now is joining from TABLE_PRODUCTS twice. 

If you could show me where to place the print_r() for it to show the report I would greatly appreciate it:

http://pastebin.com/xupaHhf6

Comment: On line 13 (from that pastebin) add `print_r("MYSQL ERROR: ".$db->ErrorMsg());`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything :-\, right now I'm trying to get the thing working using a UNION with no luck.

Here's an updated pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ikmVmuCC

Comment: Then ADOdb throws an exception. This is going nowhere. Grab that query and test it in mysql directly. Through commandline mysql, PHPMyAdmin or  any other manager.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! I am now receiving the following error on my last pastebin:

#1054 - Unknown column 'opc.products_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. You have been a great assistance!